# Having an issue with my div alignments

Tags: css, html, alignment

Hi all I seem to be having serious trouble getting my div to go exactly where I need it to. Here is a link to the [website](http://www.artistic-creations-by-mymindseye.com/).

As you can see my slideshow is supposed to be in the frame, but in now way shape or form am I able to make it do so.

here is [the link to the style sheet](http://www.artistic-creations-by-mymindseye.com/style.css) that Im working with.
Some help would be much appreciated, I've googled page upon page and can't seem to find any solution so I can to the place that I've found help from before.

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideshow {
position: relative;
left: auto;
right: auto;
top: 119px;}
```

This CSS looks horrible (width of `#content`, `left:auto; margin-top: auto`...)

My suggestion is to make a fresh start and get rid of all those autos.

Answer (score 0):

This'll fix what ails you:

```
#contentbox {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Personal preference:

```
#wowslider-container1 {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "margin-top: auto;"?

```
#content {
height: 374px;
width: 524;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to add

```
.ws_images{
    margin-top: 122px; 
}
```